# Changing the zoom on an embedded Google Map is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, iframe

I went to Google Maps and looked up my business location. I clicked the menu and clicked "Share or embed map." Below is the code I received from this:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="300" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2838.140854905187!2d-93.25362548400399!3d44.65547377909972!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x87f637fd87564a85%3A0x8af98c0084446fb5!2sAnchor+Bank+Lakeville!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1493732032364" style="border:0" width="400"></iframe>
```

This code doesn't look like any of the others I have seen in threads asking similar questions, I'm not sure why this is but this could be part of my issue.

I am trying to set the map to zoom out slightly, because currently the small map cuts off my marker. I have tried adding `&z=nn` to the end of the src but this hasn't worked.

Comment: Hi Callie! Can you share your code tries please?

Comment: <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="300" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2838.140854905187!2d-93.25362548400399!3d44.65547377909972!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x87f637fd87564a85%3A0x8af98c0084446fb5!2sAnchor+Bank+Lakeville!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1493732032364" style="border:0" width="400"></iframe>

Sorry I didn't realize my code didn't publish!

Comment: Set up the map the way you want the embedded map to appear before you click "Share or embed map" (with the correct zoom).

Comment: I tried that but I kept getting the same result once I added it to the page.

Comment: I switched browsers and it worked now! (IE is standard at my office - but it worked in Chrome). Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?z=12&t=m&q=loc:"your latitude here ignore the quotes"+"your longtitude here ignore the quotes"&output=embed" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>
```

You can get the coordinates by right clicking on google maps and selecting "What is this place?" context menu. This will be a simpler approach. Also, you can change the zoom bye changing the z paramater from the url.